# How to POST Data from HTML Page via WebApi in MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Function which is use to take input data from HTML

```
 function saveclickdata()
    {

        var allData = {
            InvNo:document.getElementById('TbInvNo').value,
            GrossSale:document.getElementById('TbOrderTotal').value,
            discount:document.getElementById('TbDiscount').value,
            CusCash:document.getElementById('TbCash').value,
            CusBal:document.getElementById('TbBalance').value,       
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: "\Controllers\POSController.cs\SaveData",
            type: 'POST',
            data: allData,
            success: function (res) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alet("Error");
            }
        });
```

Api which is in controller used to post data

```
[HttpPost]
JsonResult SaveData(POSMater collection)
    { 

        if (collection.InvNo.ToString() == null)
        {
            var LocalInvNo = (from b in db.TblPOSMasters select b).FirstOrDefault();
            int MaxInvNo = Convert.ToInt32(LocalInvNo) + 1;
            collection.InvNo = MaxInvNo;
            TblPOSMaster master = new TblPOSMaster();
            master.InvNo = collection.InvNo;
            master.AddBy = 1;
            master.AddDate = DateTime.Now;
            master.CashStatus = "A";
            master.CompId = 1;
            //master.CreditAmt = collection.CreditAmt;
            //master.CrCardNo = collection.CrCardNo;
            master.CusCash = collection.CusCash;
            master.CusId = 1;
            master.GrossSale = collection.GrossSale;

            db.TblPOSMasters.Add(master);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(collection);

        }
        return Json(collection);

    }
```

What should i do? My html button working properly but still not able to call api

Comment: Have you intentionally omitted the URL or are you trying to post to " url: "\Controllers\POSController.cs\SaveData"?

Comment: The url seems wrong, should it be \Controllers\POS\SaveData ? I would suggest using the MVC helpers to get the url.

Comment: try using `url: '@Url.Action("SaveData", "POS")'` in your ajax call

Comment: @JamieD77 bro its not working and alse i have tried \Contollers\POS\SaveData its also not working

Comment: url should be ControllerName\ActionName so here : POS\SaveData

Answer (score 0):

I think you ought to use forward slashes (`/`) in your URL